# Is there a way to serialize an object in debug mode?

Tags: debugging, testing, serialization

Often I will fix an obscure bug involving very complicated classes.  Now I want to build an automated regression test for it.  Ideally there would be a way to serialize the class from debug mode, and re-instantiate it in the unit test.  For simplicity you can assume the classes are serializable, like a vector of a few thousand specific Integers.  Is there a way to do this, or do I need to spend substantial amounts of time reconstructing the class in code?

I am mainly looking for an answer in java/eclipse, but I would be interested in hearing about any IDE with this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window > Show View > Display. You can run arbitrary commands at any point in debug mode where a breakpoint is set.  If the class is seralizable, it can be serialized from there.

Comment: The view is actually called `Debug Shell` rather than `Display`, at least on my Eclipse (`Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers. Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)`)